# Using Livebindings to Assign Several Field Values to an FMX MetropolisUI TListBox Item.Text

Tags: delphi, microsoft-metro, firemonkey, livebindings, tlistbox

I am coding a FMX Metropolis UI application and trying to assign two field values of type string to the Item.Title member of TListBox by LiveBindings technology (using expression engine).

When I use a TBindList in the following way:

```
object BindList1: TBindList
  Category = 'Lists'
  ControlComponent = ListBox1
  SourceComponent = BindSourceDB1
  FormatExpressions = <
    item
      ControlExpression = 'Text'
      SourceExpression =
        'FieldByName("name1").Text + " " + Field' +
        'ByName("name2").Text'
    end>
  FormatControlExpressions = <>
  ClearControlExpressions = <>
end
```

It assigns the 'name1 name2' string to the member `Text` but I fail to set the `ListItemStyle := MetropolisUI` as there is no such property in TBindList class

If I use `TLinkFillControlToField`

```
object LinkFillControlToField2: TLinkFillControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      Control = ListBox1
      Track = True
      FillDataSource = BindSourceDB1
      FillDisplayFieldName = 'name1'
      AutoFill = True
      BufferCount = -1
      AutoBufferCount = False
      FillExpressions = <>
      FillHeaderExpressions = <>
      FillBreakGroups = <>
    end
```

it lets me to assign `ListItemStyle` to `MetropolisUI`, but there is only one field that I can access with `FillDisplayFieldName` property and there is no `SourceExpression` field to assign `'FieldByName("name1").Text + " " + FieldByName("name2").Text'` to it.

I tried to guess context of `Item.Text` member of `TListBox` from `TBindList` but I did not manage to. I studied Delphi samples but there is no Metropolis TListBox and it seems to act in a different way than the common one. Does anybody have any ideas how to find the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the post of @house-of-dexter He gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29337522/5043424) concerning `TLabel` that encouraged me to try `TLinkFillControlToField` once again. The main issue is that the context of the fieldname can be found in `Self.Owner`.

```
object LinkFillControlToField2: TLinkFillControlToField
  Category = 'Quick Bindings'
  DataSource = BindSourceDB1
  Control = ListBox1
  Track = True
  FillDataSource = BindSourceDB1
  AutoFill = True
  BufferCount = -1
  AutoBufferCount = False
  ListItemStyle = 'MetropolisUI'
  FillExpressions = <
    item
      SourceMemberName = 'name1'
      ControlMemberName = 'Title'
      CustomFormat = 'Self.Owner.name1.text+" "+Self.Owner.name2.text'
    end>
  FillHeaderExpressions = <>
  FillBreakGroups = <>
end
```