# Query a SQL Database & Edit the found data set

Tags: sql, delphi

I know this question has probably been asked before I just can't manage to get mine going. I set up my SQL to have two tables but in this instance I will only be using one called 'Book'. It has various columns but the ones I want to work with is called 'WR', 'Customer', 'Contact',  'Model', 'SN', 'Status', 'Tech', 'WDone' and 'IN'.

I want to enter text into a editbox called `edtWR` and I want the button `btnSearch` to search the 'WR' column until it has a match (all of the entries will be different). Once it has that it must write 'Customer', 'Contact',  'Model', 'SN', 'Status' to labels, lets call them `lblCustomer` `lblContact` `lblModel` `lblSN` & `lblStatus`.

Once the person has verified that that is the 'WR' that they want the must enter text into edit boxes and one memo called `edtTech`, `mmoWDone` and `edtIN` and click on `btnUpdate`. that should then update that record.

I have 3 ADO Connections on called `dtbOut` thats my ADOConnection1, `tableOut` thats my ADOTable and `dataOut` thats by ADODataSet. dataOut's command text is `Select * From Book` if it helps.

I can get the whole process to work perfectly on a access database but with almost no experience on SQL I need help. I will add code for the Access database in case it is needed for reference.

```
 procedure TFOut.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
     dataout.Filter := 'WR = ''' + 'WR ' + edtwr.Text + '''';
     dataout.Filtered := True;
     dataout.First;

     lblcustomer.Caption := 'Customer: ' + dataout.FieldByName('Customer').AsString;
     lblcontact.Caption := 'Contact: ' + dataout.FieldByName('Contact').AsString;

     lblSN.Caption := 'SN: ' + dataout.FieldByName('SN').AsString;
     lblModel.Caption := 'Model: ' + dataout.FieldByName('Model').AsString;
     lblstatus.Caption := 'Status: ' + dataout.FieldByName('Status').AsString;


procedure TFOut.btnUpdateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   dataout.Edit;
   dataout.FieldByName('Tech').AsString := edtTech.Text;
   dataout.FieldByName('WDone').AsString := mmoWDone.Lines.GetText;
   dataout.FieldByName('IN').AsString  := edtIN.Text;
   dataout.Post;
end
```

Do I need any additional components on my form for me to be able to do this in SQL, what do I need and how do I even start. Ive read a lot of things and it seems line I will need to get a `ADOQuery1` but when it comes to the `ADOQuery1.SQL` part I fall off the wagon. I have also tried it the Access way and I can search but as soon as I try to update I get a "Insufficient key column information for updating or refreshing" Error, witch I also have no idea how to address.

If I need to state the question otherwise, please explain how to change to make it more clear and if I need to add anything in the whole explanation or code, please inform me of what.

Comment: Why aren't you using data-aware components such as TDBEdit, TDBMemo and TDBText, instead of TEdit, TMemo and TLabel ones?

Comment: I'm not using data-aware components. Its just plain TEdit, TMemo and TLabels components. What made you think its Data-aware components? @MartynA

Comment: Thanx for the edit @marc_s

Comment: "I'm not using data-aware components."  I know, that's why I asked why you aren't using them, because they automatically take care of the things like copying dataset field values back and forth to their GUI representations.  There is usually no reason to do it in code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to concentrate as I've been struggling with this question the whole day. I missed the "Why don't you" and took it as a "Why do you". Will it still work if I wanted to add text to the result label? eg: lblSN.Caption := 'SN: ' + dataout.FieldByName('SN').AsString + ' is your SN'; ? and how will this then work with the "Tech", WDone" and "IN' Fields, will they automatically update as I type text into them or will I need procedure to do that? @MartynA

Comment: If I were you, I'd put this project to one side and look at any of the countless online Delphi database tutorials, e.g. http://delphi.about.com/od/database/a/databasecourse.htm to find out how DB-aware controls save you a lot of coding, and get things right where beginners tend not to.  Btw, the most instructive db-aware component for a beginner is the TDBNavigator, because that helps visualize the stateful nature of Delphi's TDataSet model, which is what the operation of DB-aware components is based upon.

Comment: Even if you do not want to use DB aware components you can use LiveBindings for that. You can easily add any text to your component Captions (or Texts in FMX). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31207265/5043424) for example.

Comment: A data aware label is the `TDBText` control. How do you format its text is upon `TField`'s `OnGetText` event method implementation.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll do that. But telling me to study doesnt answer the question. I cant leave the project as its being used by the user already on an access database witch works perfect. Now I want to get it going using code. Later when when I have time I will sit down and improve on things like data-aware components and clean up the code. @MartynA

Comment: I'm afraid that SO is about specific coding questions (one per q) and your q raises a whole raft of issues, so I'll be surprised if you get a complete answer.  What database back-end are you now using, Access, Sql Server or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO isn't really the place for database tutorials, so I'm not going to
attempt one but instead focus on one basic thing that it's crucial to understand and get right in your database design before you even begin
to write a Delphi db app. (I'm going to talk about this in terms of
Sql Server, not MS Access.)

You mentioned getting an error "Insufficient key column information for updating or refreshing" which you said you had no idea how to address.

A Delphi dataset (of any sort, not just an ADO one) operates by maintaining a logical cursor which which points at exactly one row in the dataset.  When you open a (non-empty) dataset, this cursor is pointing at the first row in the dataset and you can move the cursor around using various TDataSet methods such as `Next` & `Prior`, `First`, `Last` and `MoveBy`.  Some, but not all, types of TDataSet implement its `Locate` method which enables you to go to a row which matches criteria you specify, other types, not. Delphi's ADO components *do* implement `Locate` (btw, `Locate` operates on rows you're already retrieved from the server, it's not for finding rows *on the server*).

One of the key ideas of Sql-oriented TDataSets such as TAdoQuery is that you can leave it to automatically generate Sql statements to do Updates, Deletes and Inserts.  This is not only a significant productivity aid, but it avoids coding errors and omissions when you try to do it yourself.

If you observe ADO doing its stuff against an MS Sql Server table using SS's Profiler utility, then with a well-designed database, you'll find that it does this quite nicely and efficiently *provided* the database design follows one cardinal rule, namely that there must be a way to uniquely identify a particular row in a table.  The most common way to do this is to include in each table, usually as the first column, an int(eger) ID column, and to define it as the "Primary key" of the table.  Although there are other methods to generate a suitable ID value to go in this column, Sql Server has a specific column type, 'Identity' which takes care of this on the server.

Once a table has such a column, the ADO layer (which is a data-access layer provided by Windows that dataset components such as TAdoQuery sit upon) can  automatically generate Sql statements to do Updates and Deletes, e.g.

```
Delete from Table1 where Table1ID = 999
```

and

```
Update Table1 set SomeCharField = 'SomeValue' where Table1ID = 666
```

and you can leave it to the AdoQuery to pick up the ID value for a newly-inserted row from the server.

One of the helpful aspects of leaving the Sql to be generated automatically is that it ensures that the Sql only affects a single row and so avoids affecting more rows than you intend.

Once you've got this key aspect of your database design correct, you'll find that Delphi's TDataSet descendants such as TAdoQuery and its DB-aware components can deal with most simple database applications without you having to write any Sql statements at all to update, insert or delete
rows.  Usually, however, you do still need to write Sql statements to retrieve the rows you want from the server by using a 'Where' clause to restrict the rows retrieved to a sub-set of the rows on the server.

Maybe your next step should be to read up on parameterized Sql queries, to reduce your exposure to "Sql Injection":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

as it's best to get into the habit of writing Sql queries using parameters.  Btw, Sql Injection isn't just about Sql being intercepted and modified when it's sent over the internet: there are forms of injection where a malicious user who knows what they're doing can simply type in some extra Sql statements where the app "expects" them simply to specify some column value as a search criterion.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it going now. I will read up about the data-aware components and sql as suggested once I can have some time aside from working during the day and coding during the night. Thanx. One thing last thing, Access has the ID field automatically created. So I managed to get one in  the SQL database as well but where access is automatically creating numbers for each new record address, I have to manually add it into SQL. I know I am doing something wrong then, is it a quick fix? If not, I'll read your suggestion and figure it out later. @MartynA

Comment: If you're talking about your btnUpdateClick method, the first thing to do would be to check the IndexFieldNames + IndexFields properties of your TAdoDataSet. One or other of these should include the field/column names that you want the rows to by ordered by **and** the ID field for the table.  Try that, and if you're still stuck, post a new q specifically (and only) about that.

Comment: Thanx a million. I will have a look tomorrow after work again. @MartynA